# Rodar JSF em Jetty 9

Tags: java, jsf

Estou tendo problemas ao rodar JSF no Jetty 9. É necessário algum jar especifico dentro da aplicação ou alguma configuração no Jetty?

Comment: Sua pergunta está muito vaga. Qual erro você está tendo? Tem como você editar sua pergunta adicionando o stack trace?

Answer (score 2):

Galera, o erro que estava tendo era a seguinte exception:
Error Could not find Factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

Encontrei no próprio StackOverflow alguem com erro parecido e a solução no seguinte endereço:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9273439/error-could-not-find-factory-javax-faces-context-facescontextfactory

Valeu